# Using web.config transform to conditionally update an element

Tags: web-config, transformation

I am trying to configure transformation rules for a web.config to create or update a connection string. The rules are simple:

1. If a connection string with a given name ("MyDatabase") is present, it should not be touched.
2. If there is no connection string with a given name, it should be inserted.

But I can't figure out if this is possible. If I just specify "add" element in my web.config.transform, it inserts connectionString element even if there is already one with such name. But if I specify xdt:Transform="Replace", then it will be replaced. I've found a [good article](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html) on the subject, and it lists scenarios Replace,Insert,Delete. But I need "InsertIfNotExists".

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blog [Custom web.config transforms and merges](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/07/27/custom-web-config-transforms-and-merges) describes 
extensions  Merge and  MergeBefore transforms that would insert an element if it's missing but leave the element alone if it's already present.

To use a custom transform, you have to import the relevant namespace in your transformation XML:

```
<xdt:Import assembly="AppHarbor.TransformTester"
    namespace="AppHarbor.TransformTester.Transforms"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, if you wish to update an element in the web.config via a config transform and the element is not present, you can simply add an empty element in web.config and configure your web.Release.config like so:

web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpModules>
</httpModules>
...
```

web.Release.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</httpModules>
...
```

This way, you can merge your new properties into the web config upon deployment!